# uCommerce - add dynamic property to order line

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce

I have hit a problem building a uCommerce site based on top of the demo razor store available http://thesitedoctor.co.uk/portfolio/avenue-clothingcom/

The demo uses servicestack and the ucommerceapi for its basket functions.

I am trying to add a dynamic property to the basket (on an order line) at the point where the user clicks buy. I traced through the productpage.js file and amended the code to add a new property ('message'):

```
function (data) {
var variant = data.Variant;
$.uCommerce.addToBasket(
{
    sku: variant.Sku,
    variantSku: variant.VariantSku,
    quantity: qty,
    message: $('#personalisedMessage').val()
},
function () {
    updateCartTotals(addToCartButton);
}
);
});
```

using firebug, i checked the data that is being posted

```
addToExistingLine: true
message: "this is a message"
quantity:"1" 
sku: "Product (options: none)"
variantSku:""
```

Posting this does not cause an error, but I cannot tell if it has worked either - I cannot find it in the database, assuming that it would be stored in OrderProperty table. In this scenario, I am 'buying' a product with no variations.

Any help is greatly appreciated with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box you can't add order/line item properties via the API like that. The API payload that you've added to is specified although valid JSON won't get interpreted/used by the API.

Instead what you'll need to do is add your own method to the API. To do this you'll need to implement a service from IUCommerceApiService and then you can do what you need. I've created an example (untested) below and will get it added to the demo store as I think it's a useful bit of functionality to have.

```
public class AddOrderLineProperty
{
    public int? OrderLineId { get; set; }

    public string Sku { get; set; }

    public string VariantSku { get; set; }

    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
public class AddOrderLinePropertyResponse : IHasResponseStatus
{
    public AddOrderLinePropertyResponse() { }

    public AddOrderLinePropertyResponse(UCommerce.EntitiesV2.OrderLine line)
    {
        if (line == null)
        {
            UpdatedLine = new LineItem();
            return;
        }

        var currency = SiteContext.Current.CatalogContext.CurrentCatalog.PriceGroup.Currency;
        var lineTotal = new Money(line.Total.Value, currency);

        UpdatedLine = new LineItem()
        {
            OrderLineId = line.OrderLineId,
            Quantity = line.Quantity,
            Sku = line.Sku,
            VariantSku = line.VariantSku,
            Price = line.Price,
            ProductName = line.ProductName,
            Total = line.Total,
            FormattedTotal = lineTotal.ToString(),
            UnitDiscount = line.UnitDiscount,
            VAT = line.VAT,
            VATRate = line.VATRate
        };
    }

    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }

    public LineItem UpdatedLine { get; set; }
}
public class AddOrderLinePropertyService : ServiceBase<AddOrderLineProperty>, IUCommerceApiService
{
    protected override object Run(AddOrderLineProperty request)
    {
        var orderLineId = request.OrderLineId;
        var sku = request.Sku;
        var variantSku = request.VariantSku;

        var orderLine = findOrderLine(orderLineId, sku, variantSku);
        addPropertyToOrderLine(orderLine, request.Key, request.Value);

        TransactionLibrary.ExecuteBasketPipeline();
        var newLine = findOrderLine(orderLineId, sku, variantSku);
        return new AddOrderLinePropertyResponse(newLine);
    }

    private void addPropertyToOrderLine(OrderLine orderLine, string key, string value)
    {
        if (orderLine == null)
            return;

        orderLine[key] = value;

        orderLine.Save();
    }

    private static OrderLine findOrderLine(int? orderLineId, string sku, string variantSku)
    {
        return orderLineId.HasValue
                            ? getOrderLineByOrderLineId(orderLineId)
                            : getOrderLineBySku(sku, variantSku);
    }

    private static OrderLine getOrderLineBySku(string sku, string variantSku)
    {
        return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(variantSku)
                            ? getOrderLines().FirstOrDefault(l => (l.Sku == sku))
                            : getOrderLines().FirstOrDefault(l => (l.Sku == sku && l.VariantSku == variantSku));
    }

    private static OrderLine getOrderLineByOrderLineId(int? orderLineId)
    {
        return getOrderLines().FirstOrDefault(l => l.OrderLineId == orderLineId);
    }

    private static ICollection<OrderLine> getOrderLines()
    {
        return TransactionLibrary.GetBasket().PurchaseOrder.OrderLines;
    }
}
```

You'll need to add the new method to uCommerce.jQuery.js as well something like this:

```
addOrderLineProperty: function (options, onSuccess, onError) {
    var defaults = {
        orderLineId: 0
    };
    var extendedOptions = $.extend(defaults, options);
    callServiceStack({ AddOrderLineProperty: extendedOptions }, onSuccess, onError);
}
```

Let me know if you have any issues using it.

Tim